# Is the following an example of the "dummy it"?

Tags: pronouns

> The first time a woman touched his books. **It** felt intimate, like his body was being caressed

Is this an example of the "[dummy it](https://www.thoughtco.com/dummy-it-in-grammar-1690414#:%7E:text=Also%20known%20as%20ambient%20%22it,meaning%20but%20no%20lexical%20meaning.)"? Or "it" here refers to the action in the first sentence?

Comment: I think the pronoun refers to the previous sentence. "The touch" is what felt intimate. I even think they should have been separated by a comma. Otherwise _That was the first time a woman touched his books. It felt intimate, like his body was being caressed_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It" here refers to the previous sentence, the woman touching his books.

Answer (score 1):

> The touch [of the woman on his books] felt intimate, ...

For "it" to be dummy, it shouldn't refer to anything in particular. Here, it refers to the previous sentence and to the act of touching the books (or to the touch itself).